# Restricting class method access to one other class

Tags: c#, access-modifiers, restriction

Greetings.

I have two classes, 'Database' and 'Group.' I want to be able to create instances of 'Group' and call methods on those instances from within 'Database' and to be able to distribute 'Group' instance references publicly. However, I do not want to provide public access to the constructor or other methods in 'Group.'

I originally thought that I could achieve this access restriction by making 'Group' a private inner class of 'Database,' but I discovered that I couldn't publicly distribute references to 'Group' if it was private. Also, my attempts at making 'Group' a public inner class failed, because if its methods were all private, 'Database' couldn't access them, and if they were public, access was possible beyond 'Database.'

**I am looking for a best-practice technique for solving or circumventing this problem.** Maybe I missed a necessary keyword somewhere? Nothing I have found thus far in my research has indicated that C# permits this granularity of control. I found a messy way to get around the problem, as I've provided below in code. Its essence is this: before every call in 'Database' to a method in 'Group,' set a field in 'Database,' publicly readable but only privately settable, that 'Group''s methods all check in their creating instances of 'Database' before performing their intended operations. When reading the field (via a public method in 'Database,') the field is reset, preventing any further method calls on 'Group' until 'Database' sets the field again.

```
public class Database {

    // Field; true if Database has just authorized a method call to a %Group.
    private bool group_isNextCallAuthorized = false;

    // Invoked before every method call to a %Group.
    private void Group_AuthorizeNextCall() {
        group_isNextCallAuthorized = true;
 }

    // Method, ordinarily called from %Group, that checks its creating %Database
    //  that the %Database itself authorized the method call on the %Group. It
    //  automatically resets the authorization to false to prepare for the next,
    //  perhaps unauthorized, method call.
    public bool Group_IsNextCallAuthorized() {
        bool previousValue = group_isNextCallAuthorized;
        group_isNextCallAuthorized = false;
        return previousValue;
    }

    // Constructor; creates a demo %Group.
    public Database() {

        // Create a %Group, first authorizing the action.
        Group_AuthorizeNextCall();
        Group group = Group.Create(this);

        // Call some method on the group
        Group_AuthorizeNextCall();
        group.SomeGroupMethod();

    }

}

public class Group {

    // Field; refers to the %Database that created this %Group instance.
    private Database db;

    // Generates an instance of %Group, requiring the creating %Database as an
    //  argument. After checking that the %Database %db isn't null, it verifies
    //  that %db actually requests and authorized this %Group's creation via the
    //  %Group_IsNextCallAuthorized(.) method provided by %Database.
    public static Group Create(Database db) {

        // It will not create a dud instance of %Group; it will throw an exception
        //  instead.
        if ((db == null) || !db.Group_IsNextCallAuthorized())
            throw new System.Exception("Unauthorized access.");

        return new Group(db);
    }

    // This constructor is referenced internally by static %Create(.) as above.
    private Group(Database db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    // This is an arbitrary method showing that it must check that the %Database
    //  that created this %Group authorized this method call before it will
    //  perform its intended function.
    public void SomeGroupMethod() {
        if (!db.Group_IsNextCallAuthorized())
            throw new System.Exception("Unauthorized access.");

        // intended functionality...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to expose an interface IGroup to the outside parts of your code.  This interface would only have getters on the properties, whatever methods you want accessible, etc.  Then Database would operate on the Group class, having full access to all properties/methods, and returning IGroup

Comment: This does look to me like a good idea. It does seem to cripple automatic type-checking when I want to use a 'Group' as an argument to a 'Database' method from outside 'Database' though, since I would instead have to pass an 'IGroup,' which could be implemented by any class. Nonetheless, since I can verify types manually within 'Database' anyway, this technique looks like it could substantially de-complicate my code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested class approach. Probably not the most eligant one since tightly coupled but will do the trick.

```
 public class DataBase 
 {
      private class Group 
      {
            private Group() {} 

      }

      private Group group = null;

      public DataBase() 
      {
         this.group = new Group();
      }

      public Group 
      {
         get 
         {
            return this.group;

         }   
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

To express this visibility using C# access rules, you need to reverse the class nesting: make Database a nested class inside Group, so it can access the private bits of Group.

Comment: I think your method works for my problem as I described it. However, I would actually like to be able to extend this code to allow another class similar to 'Group' to also be created from 'Database' in the same manner, and with the same access restrictions. It is not obvious to me whether your approach can be adapted to this problem change.

Comment: In that case, your only option is to use `internal` instead of `private`, since the CLR has no concept of friend classes.  You may need to make this object model its own assembly in order to demarcate how far `internal` extends.